# .htaccess - image filed treated as PHP file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim

I wrote a simple PHP REST application and I have a problem with serving static files. My directory structure looks as follows :

- public

  - content (here are static files)
  - index.php
- src (my application sources)
- vendor (Composer dependencies)

I have two .htaccess files in my project - in root directory and in public directory :

root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
```

public .htaccess (standard Slim template)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA]
```

These configuration looks like that because I wanted all requests to be redirected to public directory and omit that part in request uri to have http://host.com/rest/XXX instead http://host.com/rest/public/XXX.

Right now I can't access files using http://host.com/rest/content/file-test.ext - it seems like it's treated as PHP file because I getting error :

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=30) state=0 in /rest/public/content/file-test.ext on line 298

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in /rest/public/content/file-test.ext on line 298
```

I already tried to put separate .htaccess file inside content directory with `RewriteEngine off` or `php_flags engine off`.

I can't change any webserver configuration because hosting is provided by 3rd part person I can't even request any changes. host.com/rest i set to my document root and when I connect via FTP I can't go upwards from that directory so solutions regarding webserver configuration changes are not correct in my case.

Please help me to get static files working !

Comment: If you're using slim, why don't you just prepend the routes with `/rest/` instead of doing rewrites? And then just set an alias for `/rest/content` to point to `/public/content`? One suggestion would be to actually point your web root to the public folder and keep your source code outside of the web root

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - I already have routes specified as `/rest/method`. What do you mean by alias ? Do you know some method to pass Slim requests to specific directory to return file stream ? I can't set public directory to content root because server is not managable by me and have no opportunity to request that change.

Comment: Your webserver should have public folder configured as the document root.

Comment: I have webserver document root set and I can't change it or navigate upwards. I'm just able to connect via FTP and upload files without any oppurtunity to go up from that document root directory. Address is also set to that document root directory and I can't change it. I wouldn't ask about that htaccess config if I will be able to handle that issue in other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize Slim: it retains control in your hands and you don't solve the problem with `.htaccess`.

Also:

- you can change the route or containing folder anytime you wish.
- you can set additional headers e.g. for caching.

```php
$app->get('/content/{pathToImage}', function($request, $response, $args) {
    $pathToFile = $args['pathToImage'];
    $containingFolder = '../content/'; // the actual folder where files are stored
    // if you want to omit file extension in the url, we'll have to find it out
    $matches = glob($containingFolder.$fileName.'.*');
    if ($matches) {
        $clientImagePath = array_shift($matches); // let's grab the first file matching our mask
        $clientImage = @file_get_contents($clientImagePath);
        $finfo = new \Finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $response->write($clientImage);
        return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', $finfo->buffer($clientImage));
    } else {
        // if no matches found, throw exception that will be handled by Slim
        throw new \Slim\Exception\NotFoundException($request, $response);
    }
});
```

In case URLs like `content/image.png` (having file extension) is acceptable for you, you can do this in a simpler way:

```php
$app->get('/assets/images/{pathToImage}', function($request, $response, $args) {
    $pathToFile = $args['pathToImage'];
    $path = '../content/'.$fileName;
    $image = @file_get_contents($path);
    $finfo = new \Finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $response->write($image);
    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', $finfo->buffer($image));
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Working as I expected. I only need to add validation for non-existing files :) Great solution !